# Program C Simple Little Program Mistake

Tags: c

it's just a simple program I made. Not sure why it's not working, maybe you guys can help.

Thanks in advance.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "HuntersInfo.h"

int main()
{

    int girlsAge = (AGE / 2) + 7;
    printf("%s can date girls who are %d or older.\n", MYNAME, girlsAge);

    return 0;
}
```

HuntersInfo.h:

```
#define MYNAME "Hunter Shutt"
#define AGE "14"
```

Comment: The age is a string not a number, Also post what is gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the preprocessor runs, you're left with:

```
int main()
{

    int girlsAge = ("14" / 2) + 7;
    printf("%s can date girls who are %d or older.\n", "Hunter Shutt", girlsAge);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, `"14"` is a string, not a number.

`#define AGE 14` would fix it, but you're better using variables rather than typeless defines, since you'll get much more helpful errors and warnings:

```
static const char* MYNAME = "Hunter Shutt";
static const int AGE = 14;
```

Comment: I know, I was following along in a tutorial. Thanks so much! And thank you everyone who helped me!

Answer (score 2):

change

```
#define AGE "14"
```

to

```
#define AGE 14
```

its not working because you are performing division on string.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing some math with a string (you set up age as "14"). Change the line
`#define AGE "14"`
to
`#define AGE 14`

`#define` pretty much tells the compiler that every time it sees whatever symbol is after it (in this case AGE) with the one after that (you've set it to "14").